# Updating a singular row in a trigger SQLite

Tags: sqlite, triggers, sql-update

Table rental has values (ID, odo_out, date),
table vehicle has values (ID, odo, car),
both with more columns but not relevant to this.

I have attempted to create a trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER odo_update AFTER INSERT ON rental
BEGIN
UPDATE rental SET odo_out = (SELECT Vehicle.odo FROM Vehicle WHERE rental.ID = Vehicle.ID)
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Vehicle WHERE Vehicle.ID = rental.ID);
END;
```

which should detect a NULL for rental.odo_out and replace it with the value in Vehicle.odo for corresponding ID. This does work, but it updates every row in table, whereas I want it to ONLY update the row with NULL, ie the new row being inserted. An ID can be repeated multiple times in the rental table. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the condition so that only the new row is updated.
This is where you need the keyword `NEW` to refer to the columns of the new row:

```
CREATE TRIGGER odo_update AFTER INSERT ON rental
WHEN NEW.odo_out IS NULL
BEGIN
  UPDATE rental 
  SET odo_out = (SELECT odo FROM Vehicle WHERE ID = NEW.ID)
  WHERE ID = NEW.ID;
END;
```